# Reverting text and entry boxes on a tkinter canvas

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, tkinter-canvas

In this code, entering an integer and clicking the process button shows a number of entry boxes. I want the back button to act as a reverting button which makes the entry boxes disappear and bring the GUI to its original state. How can I do this?

```
import tkinter as tk
import tkinter.ttk as ttk

hht=[]
tks = []

window = tk.Tk()

def open_window(pll):
    numh = int(pll)

    l0 = tk.Label(canvas, text="H                                      T", font="Calibri 12", bg="white")
    canvas.create_window(390,125, window=l0, anchor=tk.NW)

    for i in range(numh):
        hht.append(tk.StringVar())
        tks.append(tk.StringVar())

        en = ttk.Entry(canvas, textvariable = hht[i])
        en.config({"background": "gainsboro"})
        canvas.create_window(350, 150+i*25, window=en, anchor=tk.NW)

        aen = ttk.Entry(canvas, textvariable = tks[i])
        aen.config({"background": "gainsboro"})
        canvas.create_window(500, 150+i*25, window=aen, anchor=tk.NW)

ws = window.winfo_screenwidth()
hs = window.winfo_screenheight()
w = 700 # width for the Tk root
h = 410  # height for the Tk root
x = (ws / 2) - (w / 2)
y = (hs / 2) - (h / 2)
window.geometry('%dx%d+%d+%d' % (w, h, x, y))  
canvas = tk.Canvas(window,bg="white",width=700, height=410, highlightthickness=0)
canvas.pack()

l13= tk.Label(canvas, text="Enter Numbers", font="Calibri 16", bg="white")
canvas.create_window(300,8, window=l13, anchor=tk.NW)

l0 = tk.Label(canvas, text="Entry", font="Calibri 12", bg="white")
canvas.create_window(15,58, window=l0, anchor=tk.NW)

PLz = tk.DoubleVar()
entry_PLz = ttk.Entry(canvas, textvariable=PLz)
entry_PLz.config({"background": "gainsboro"})
canvas.create_window(270,70, window=entry_PLz)


submit_button = ttk.Button(canvas, text="Process >>", command=lambda: open_window(PLz.get()))
canvas.create_window(300, 100, window=submit_button, anchor=tk.NW)

back_button = ttk.Button(canvas, text="Back")
canvas.create_window(450, 100, window=back_button, anchor=tk.NW)

window.resizable(False, False)
window.mainloop()
```

Comment: Have you tried simply saving the entry widgets in a list, and then using the list to destroy the items?

Comment: @BryanOakley no, can you suggest any examples?

Comment: You can using `tag` option in `create_window()` inside `open_window()`, for example, `canvas.create_window(..., tag='added_item')`.  Then `back_button = ttk.Button(..., command=lambda: canvas.delete('added_item'))`.

Comment: You need to clear `hht` and `tks` before the for loop as well.

Comment: @acw1668 I want to clear everything from the function open_window(). And I got this error (TypeError: open_window() got an unexpected keyword argument 'tag') when I used tag

Comment: Not using `tag` in `open_window()`, use in all `create_window(...)` inside `open_window()` function.